# What famous theorems or results were proven by female mathematicians?

Tags: mathematicians

We know that there were/are many famous female mathematicians who influenced the mathematics as we know it today, but their numbers are few compared to male mathematicians. While we have numerous famous results by many male mathematicians like Gauss, Euler and many others, what are famous results bearing the name of a female mathematician which also have a very deep impact on our understanding of mathematics?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypatia

Comment: @KprimeX what are you asking? Whether or not there exist any results proved by women which are as famous as any results by any other mathematicians? Whether or not there exist any results proved by women which are as famous as any results by Gauss and Euler? Whether or not there exist any results proved by women which are as famous as the most famous results by Gauss and Euler?

Comment: I started thinking about all the important theorems named "Somebody's theorem/lemma/etc." that I know, and realized that, for a substantial fraction of them, I actually *don't know* the gender of the person they're named after, at least not beyond the default cultural assumption that a majority of them are *probably* male. Even knowing their given name doesn't always help, if it's non-gender-specific or from a culture whose names I don't easily recognize as male or female specific.

Comment: The MRDP theorem solved Hilbert's tenth problem (to the negative). The R in MRDP references [Julia Robinson](http://www.awm-math.org/noetherbrochure/Robinson82.html).

Comment: The question is trivial. Easy search on the internet gives plenty of examples. Therefore I vote to close.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: All questions are to some extent "ignorant", but lacking any basic attempt at research is grounds for downvote and/or close on most SE sites.

Comment: Sofia Kovalevskaya  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sofia_Kovalevskaya Alicia Stott https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alicia_Boole_Stott

Comment: See also https://www.agnesscott.edu/lriddle/women/chronol.htm

Comment: @R.. that may be so, but it seems people want to close this one because they are uncomfortable with the question. I've researched it, and while there are lists of women mathematicians, and famous ones, there is little which places their achievements in the context of all mathematics, or their results in the context of all "famous results". I would post a proper answer but I don't have the rep.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maryam_Mirzakhani Won the fields medal

Comment: As far as I can tell no woman has won the Cole Prize, Wolf Prize or Bocher Prize.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: A better reason to close this question would be that it seems to have devolved into a [list question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124450/what-is-the-definition-of-a-list-question), with each answerer posting a single example, or at most a handful, without any attempt to consolidate them into a single definitive answer. Such questions tend to be a poor fit for SE; see our [help/dont-ask] for more details. They *can* sometimes be rescued by a particularly good and comprehensive answer, but none has showed up here so far.

Comment: See also: http://www.fabpedigree.com/james/mmdiscus.htm#alsoran

Comment: I had once seen name like " Cathedeory " and a picture of her. Not sure of spelling. ( in German VNR Enzyklopedia Mathematics) but got no google results later

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constantin_Carath%C3%A9odory, Caratheodory was a male mathematician

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maria_Gaetana_Agnesi

Comment: Daubechies has [wavelets named after her](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daubechies_wavelet)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_ending_problem

Comment: See about  [Elizabeth Williams](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/11476/10106) as well.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

See at least [Emmy Noether](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emmy_Noether) :

> was a German mathematician known for her contributions to abstract algebra and theoretical physics. She was described by Pavel Alexandrov, Albert Einstein, Jean Dieudonné, Hermann Weyl, and Norbert Wiener as the most important woman in the history of mathematics. As one of the leading mathematicians of her time, she developed the theories of rings, fields, and algebras. In physics, [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) explains the connection between symmetry and conservation laws.

---

Of course, this is *only* an example; there are many others: see answers below.

Comment: This answer massively underplays the significance of Noether's work, really hugely!

Comment: Wow didn't know about Noether's theorem. thanks.

Comment: @KprimeX this theorem is very important in physics

Comment: I agree with @CameronJWhitehead. It is not possible to overstate Noether's importance. Her theorem in theoretical physics is foundational for 20th century physics, but her work in algebra is much much more extensive and is utterly foundational to all of: number theory, commutative algebra, invariant theory, and algebraic geometry.

Comment: Whereas laws of physics explains how the world works, Noether's theorem explains how laws of physics works

Comment: @KprimeX: While Emmy Noether's accomplishments are remarkable, and she surely belongs near the top of *any* list of notable mathematicians, marking an answer mentioning *only* her as accepted seems rather dismissive of all the *other* important female mathematicians mentioned in the other answers.

Comment: Actually I am not accepting Noether as the only female mathematician of highest class, I know every other female mathematicians mentioned in the answers are also as important as Noether, but I can only accept one answer and when I accepted this answer there were only 2 answers, now it grows to 10, and I am unable to accept anymore so I give +1 to every other. @IlmariKaronen

Answer (score 45):

Perhaps because of its youth, the mathematical end of Computer Science has several notable women in its history.

[Sheila Greibach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheila_Greibach) was a pioneer in the field of formal language theory, particularly in the area of context-free languages. At the time, that would have been considered more a branch of mathematics, as Computer Science wasn't really a thing of its own.

In particular, she developed [Greibach Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greibach_normal_form), which is fairly instrumental in the theory of parsing, which is extremely critical to modern programming languages.

Continuing down programming language theory, [Barbara Liskov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbara_Liskov) developed the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), which was critical in developing a formalized model for object-oriented languages. She won the Turing Award (CS equivalent of the Fields medal) for her contributions.

Did these have a "deep impact" on our understanding of mathematics? Not in the classical sense, but they've led to some amazing developments, arguably as many as the 400 years of calculus/analysis theory.

Comment: I'd like to point out that Liskov's LSP is still used as a [design rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) in modern object-oriented programming.  It is *the* thing you have to follow if you want polymorphism to make any kind of sense.

Comment: You forgot [Grace Hopper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grace_Hopper), who in 1969 won the inaugural (and incongruously named) Man of the Year award from the Data Processing Management Association.

Comment: @DavidHammen they also forgot Ada Lovelace. Not any theorem holds her name (at far as I know) but a famous programming language instead.

Comment: Wow, while knowing the principle I never knew that the **Liskov substitution principle** is named after a woman. (Well, I didn't really care, in the same sense that I don't know the gender or nationality of most other people theorems are named after.)

Comment: Yeah, Grace Hopper was huge in terms of software engineering, but less of a mathematician than Liskov or Greibach, so I thought not as well suited to the original question. The same holds with Lovelace, she is often considered the first programmer, but wasn't developing theorems like the question asked for. Still both as relevant, just in a slightly different area.

Comment: The last clause doesn't add anything, and is a bit ridiculous to boot. Calculus and analysis underpin nearly all of physics, from newtonian mechanics to GR to QM and QFT. They also underlies nearly all of engineering (not including CS): aerospace, electrical, mechanical, civil, etc are all tremendously based on calculus and physics. Computers could not be built without the models of holes and electrons used to make transistors, also based on calculus. CS is the outlier here. To say "arguably as many" is to say that CS is "arguably" as important as all other fields combined.

Comment: @ypercube: While Ada Lovelace is mostly noted as the world's first programmer, her most important contribution to computing is the invention of subroutines. Babbage wasn't convinced about the usefulness of subroutines (functions) when Lovelace described it to him until she demonstrated an example program that made good use of subroutines. So Babbage added hardware that made it possible to return from a jump. While the theoretical foundations of functions came from mathematics, the practical use of it in computer hardware was introduced by Ada Lovelace

Comment: I am actually surprised that LSP came that late; I thought it was one of those implicitly understood thing when you do OOP, and OOP came before the LSP statement.

Answer (score 32):

There is **[Sophie Germain's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain's_theorem)**, a theorem in number theory, related to Fermat's last theorem and proved by the French mathematician **[Sophie Germain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain)** (1776-1831).

Comment: Worth noting that for a while ["_She used the name of a former student Monsieur Antoine-August Le Blanc (...) fearing the ridicule attached to a female scientist_"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain).  Maybe other great mathematicians were ladies as well : ))

Answer (score 31):

There is the work by [Ada Lovelace](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/Biographies/Lovelace.html).

> In the annotations, which were called "Notes", Ada Lovelace described how the analytical engine could be programmed and gave what many consider to be the first ever computer program.

In particular, she found and corrected a bug in Babbage's algorithm for computing Bernoulli numbers:

> We discussed together the various illustrations that might be introduced: I suggested several, but the selection was entirely her own. So also was the algebraic working out of the different problems, except, indeed, that relating to the numbers of Bernoulli, which I had offered to do to save Lady Lovelace the trouble. This she sent back to me for an amendment, having detected a grave mistake which I had made in the process.

(from C Babbage, Passages from the Life of a Philosopher (London, 1864).)

Of course, the [programming language Ada](http://www.adaic.org/) is named after [her](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_%28programming_language%29).

Answer (score 25):

I found an [existence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Kowalevski_theorem) for the Cauchy Problem in partial differential equations which has been proven by [Sofia Vasilyevna Kovalevskaya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sofia_Kovalevskaya).

Comment: I'm glad to see her here. I was about to add her, but I first checked all the answers.

Answer (score 17):

[Olga Ladyzhenskaya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olga_Ladyzhenskaya) proved a result related to the Navier-Stokes equations.

The result by itself is not very famous, but the Navier-Stokes equations are.

Answer (score 17):

The following would be my top picks:

The **Sophie Germain identity** says that $a^4+4b^4=(a^2+2b^2+2ab)(a^2+2b^2-2ab)$ for $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$. This is a very simple identity but is quite useful in many problems of elementary number theory.

The **Noether normalization lemma** is a result in commutative algebra that is taught probably in the very first week of a graduate level course in algebraic geometry. One version of the result says that, for any field $\mathbb{K}$ and any f.g. commutative $\mathbb{K}$-algebra $A$, there exists a non-negative integer $k$ and algebraicly independent elements $y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_k \in A$ such that $A$ is a f.g. module over the ring $\mathbb{K}[y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_k]$.

Answer (score 16):

Danica McKellar is the McKellar in the Chayes-McKellar-Winn theorem,

Comment: I'm not sure that this satisfies the fame requirement in the question.

Comment: Danica McKellar is famous.  Her name gets 50% more hits on Google than Emmy Noether and anyone who cares about high school math education should know McKellar.  But it is true the Chayes-McKellar-Winn theorem is not widely known or influential in mathematics.

Answer (score 9):

The [Denjoy–Young–Saks theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denjoy%E2%80%93Young%E2%80%93Saks_theorem) gives some possibilities for the Dini derivatives of a function that hold almost everywhere.

[Grace Chisholm Young](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grace_Chisholm_Young) extended Denjoy's result on continuous functions to measurable functions. Her husband was [William Henry Young](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Henry_Young).

Answer (score 9):

[Ingrid Daubechies](https://ece.duke.edu/faculty/ingrid-daubechies) did pioneering work in harmonic analysis, which led for instance to the development of finite support wavelets (orthogonal and biorthogonal). This enabled wavelet theory to enter the domain digital signal processing, perhaps similarly to the invention of the [Fast Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) with respect to the mathematical Fourier transform.

Two of these wavelets, called CDF 5/3 or [CDF 9/7](http://www.getreuer.info/home/waveletcdf97) for [Cohen-**Daubechies**-Fauveau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen-Daubechies-Feauveau_wavelet), are at the core of the image compression algorithm JPEG 2000, and the [Motion JPEG 2000](http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1201549) used in the Motion Picture industry.

She was the first woman to be president of the International Mathematical Union. She was a [Noether lecturer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether_Lecture), where you can find other influential mathematician women. And she is a baroness now.

Her mathematical results not only made the path through industrial applications, but strongly modified the way people analyse data, in a multiscale (zoom-in/zoom-out) fashion.

Comment: ... and, just to quibble, she is still alive and working! :) No past tense necessary! :)

Comment: The question was... past.

Answer (score 8):

There are not female mathematicians who have had *quite* so much impact as Gauss or Euclid, for example, but this is to be expected because of historical reasons which everyone is familiar with. A quick google will have told the questioner that there are many important female mathematicians in history, but I think the question is asking for a *really* important mathematician, or at least a *well known* mathematician, like Galois who has Galois Theory named after him, or Hilbert, who has Hilbert spaces named after him.

The first person who I thought of when I read this question was Emmy Noether, who, in terms of fame, isn't quite Newton (obviously) but is *at least* Galois.

You probably aren't going to see the names of any women in the titles of any undergrad maths courses, but if you are, it will probably be Noether.

It is possible that many Ancient mathematicians were actually woman. This is certainly the case for Egypt but probably less so for Greece (although who knows?) Even in more modern times, a few woman have worked under male pseudonyms and there may be many more that we do not know about (although it is unlikely that any of the 'big name' mathematicians like Newton and Euler were actually women because their lives have been well documented). It is also possible (in fact very likely) that work by women has been plagiarised by men, so some theorems named after males may have actually been developed by females, we probably will never know how many.

Comment: Hypatia of Alexandria was mathematician.

Answer (score 6):

1. Hypatia of Alexandria (AD 350 or 370-AD 417)

She worked on several researches most significant of which included her commentaries on the Greek text-book, Arithmetica and On the Conics of Apollonius. She is remembered especially for her detailed description of the early hydrometer.

2. Émilie du Châtelet (1706-1749)

A French physicist, mathematician and writer during the Enlightenment era in Europe. In 1740, Châtelet published a book on philosophy and science called Institutions de Physique and later translated and commented on Newton’s Principia Mathematica which is its best known translation.

3. Maria Agnesi (1718-1799)

She wrote a book on math that still survives, that is: Analytical Institutions for the Use of Italian Youth in English. Another pioneering contribution was the Witch of Agnesi- a curve that she wrote the equation for.

4. Sophie Germain (1776-1831)

Sophie Germain’s paper on elasticity theory made her the first woman to be awarded from the Paris Academy of Sciences in 1816. She was also a major contributor in proving Fermat’s Last Theorem.

5. Ada Lovelace (1815-1852)

When asked to translate the memoir of Charles Babbage, the Analytical Engine, Lovelace went ahead and added her own comments and notes about a method of calculating a sequence of Bernoulli numbers: what is today known as the world’s first ever computer program subsequently making Lovelace renowned as the world’s first computer programmer.

6. Sofia Kovalevskaya (1850-1891)

She gave the Cauchy-Kovalevskaya Theorem its end result in 1875, worked on a paper in which she invented the Kovalevskaya Top and published ten papers based on mathematics and mathematical physics.

7. Emmy Noether (1882-1935)

Emmy Noether is famous for coining the Noether’s Theorem that clarifies the relationship between conservation laws and symmetry, as well as Noether’s Ring that changed the basics of abstract algebra. Noether is also famous for other theories based on non-commutative algebras, hyper-complex numbers and commutative rings.

8. Mary Cartwright (1900-1998)

She authored over a 100 papers which include her work on level curves, functions in the unit disk, topology and ordinary differential equations among others.

9. Julia Robinson (1919-1985)

She is well regarded for her work on Hilbert’s Tenth problem and decision problems.

10. Shafi Goldwasser (1958-Date)

Her research emphasizes on zero-knowledge proof, complexity theory, computation number theory and cryptography.

Comment: See about  [Elizabeth Williams](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/11476/10106) as well.

Answer (score 4):

To continue on jmite's excellent answer, [Nancy Lynch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nancy_Lynch) is a pioneer in the theory of "Distributed Systems" in Computer Science.
For example, her work with Michael J.Fischer and Mike Paterson showed that "In an asynchronous distributed system, consensus is impossible if there is one processor that crashes" which is a fundamental result in the field.

Answer (score 3):

[Karen Uhlenbeck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karen_Uhlenbeck) made huge contribution to gauge theory and more.